# Custom keybind to move cursor right one character in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, navigation, keyboard-shortcuts

I desperately need a way to bind cursor navigation to something like Alt-wasd in Visual studio. Is there a way to do this? I have looked around a lot and this specific kind of thing I can't find, which is surprising, because it is one of the most significant ways to speed up coding when VS autocompletes braces that you constantly need to move right to get out of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign custom shortcuts to the following commands: **Edit.CharLeft**, **Edit.CharRight**, **Edit.LineUp** and **Edit.LineDown**.

Comment: Thank you! I tried looking for something like that. The names were a bit cryptic but that makes perfect sense.